# jQuery - Detect when two html `<span>` contain same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html structure in my web application.
This is a group of `<div>`s which contain information about items. Specifically there are two `<span>` tags with `pending` and `done` quantities (integer values).

Clicking on other page elements will modify `pending` and `done` values.

Is it possible to track those changes and apply a class to the whole `<div>` when those values are the same?

So the whole `<div id="{{ item.id }}">` will have a green background when pending and done match and no color background when values do not match. The actual action to be done is not relevant, what I miss is understanding the right approach in jQuery to monitor values in two html fields.

```
<div id="{{ item.id }}" href="#" state="{{ item.state }}" class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span name="pending">{{ item.pending }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span name="done">{{ item.done }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using angular? if so, which version?

Comment: Which templating engine are you using (the thing that `{{ item.id }}` replaces with the content of `item.id`)?

Comment: jinja2 loads the initial value, but the value is modified by jQuery when interacting with other page elements

Comment: I am not using angular

Comment: You can iterate through children like 
$('#mydiv').children('input').each(function () { alert(this.value); });

Comment: you may consider [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or a timer function in order to test the two spans when a modification happens...

Comment: It certainly looks like the DOM is the wrong place to be comparing this data. Why not check the variables that are being written to the DOM in the first place?  `if (item.pending == item.done) {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` and `text` functions along with these selectors `'[name="pending"]'`  `'[name="done"]'`.

To listen to javascript modifications (jQuery), an alternative is to override the `.val` function.

```
var originalValFn = jQuery.fn.val;
jQuery.fn.val = function(value) {
  originalValFn.apply(this, arguments);
  if (value !== undefined) {
    $('#done').trigger('input');
    $('#pending').trigger('input');
  }
};
```

## Look at this code snippet.

The function `updateSection` must be called when the user changes the values.

```js
var target = $('#myId');

var originalValFn = jQuery.fn.val;
jQuery.fn.val = function(value) {
  originalValFn.apply(this, arguments);
  if (value !== undefined) {
    $('#done').trigger('input');
    $('#pending').trigger('input');
  }
};

var updateSection = function() {
  var pending = target.find('[name="pending"]').text();
  var done = target.find('[name="done"]').text();

  if (pending === done) {
    target.addClass('green-class');
    target.removeClass('red-class');
  } else {
    target.addClass('red-class');
    target.removeClass('green-class');
  }
}

$('#pending').on('input', function(e) {
  target.find('[name="pending"]').text(e.target.value);
  updateSection();
});

$('#done').on('input', function(e) {
  target.find('[name="done"]').text(e.target.value);
  updateSection();
});

$('#done').val('3');
$('#pending').val('4');


//updateSection();
```

```css
.green-class {
  background-color: green;
}

.red-class {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId" href="#" state="{{ item.state }}" class="item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <span name="pending">222</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <span name="done">222</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<p>Enter values to test:</p>
<input id='pending' placeholder='pending'>
<input id='done' placeholder='done'>
```

## Resources

- [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: What will be the trigger for calling `updateSection()`?

Comment: listen event will not be triggered when the values are modified by javascript function

Comment: @Ele this is really interesting. I did not know it was possible to override the val function. I however finally triggered the comparison when the jQuery/javascript modifies the value. I got the feeling that it is a cleaner approach

Comment: @M.E. yes, it's a nice way to extend the jQuery's capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Place an `input` element inside each `span` and have the values actually be stored in the `input`. Then,  set up `input` event handlers for those `input` elements that simply compare the values of the inputs. If they are the same. Apply a class.

```js
// Get inputs
var $pending = $(".pending");
var $done = $(".done");

// Set up event handler
$pending.on("input", test);
$done.on("input", test);

function test(){
  if($pending.val() === $done.val()){
    $("div#parent").addClass("match");  
  } else {
    $("div#parent").removeClass("match");  
  }
}
```

```css
input { outline:none; border:none; }
.pending { background-color:rgba(255, 100, 100, .5); }
.done { background-color:rgba(255, 255, 100, .5); }

.match { background-color:rgba(100, 255, 100, .5); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>For testing, type different (and then the same) values into the two fields</h1>

<div id="parent" href="#" state="{{ item.state }}" class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span name="pending"><input class="pending"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <span name="done"><input class="done"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will the input event be triggered when the value is modified via jQuery val() or javascript function?

Comment: @M.E. The event will be triggered anytime the values of the inputs are modified, no matter how they got modified, so you would just modify your original code to update the values of those inputs, rather than the spans.

Answer (score 1):

First: the "name" attribute only applies to input elements, you probably want to use the "id" attribute.

I would also suggest creating a function to check for equality, something like this:

```
var pendingDone = function(){
  if($("#pending").text() === $("#done").text()) {
    $("#pending").addClass("green");
    $("#done").addClass("green");
  } else {
    $("#pending").removeClass("green");
    $("#done").removeClass("green");
  }
}
```

I would suggest just calling this function in all instances that modify the values, since the change and input listener suggested in another answer will not fire if the value is modified by javascript instead of user interaction.

Comment: input listener comment is really relevant, as value is changed via javascript functions.